# Interactor or Gateway - Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture

Tags: ios, architecture, clean-architecture, onion-architecture

**Considering [Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) (or Onion Architecture)**

Let's say that as a signed in `User` in my app, I receive a deep link url `"myapp://events/[event_id]"` (via sms, for example).

I want to join that `Event` when I click the link and display the `Event`'s information on screen.

The process works like this:

- user clicks the link
- the app receives the url and extracts the `event_id`
- with the `event_id` the app retrieves the `Event`'s information
- the app saves that information in local storage
- the app sends a POST request letting the server know that a new user (me) has joined the event
- the app displays the retrieved `Event`'s information to the user

When the app sends the POST request to join the event, it sends the `current_user`'s id, which is handled by the backend (I'm using [Parse](https://www.parse.com) with Facebook login). This means that all the user authentication is handled by `Gateway`s (with Parse the `current_user`'s id comes in the form of `PFUser`, but with some other implementation it could be a `String`, so it must be handled by `Gateway`'s).

**My question is, should this whole interaction (joining the `Event`) be handled by a `Gateway` or by an `Interactor`?**

- To me it seems more logical that the `Interactor` should handle all that process:

  1. retrieving information with the `event_id`
  2. adding the `current_user` to the `Event`
  3. calling the `Gateway` to save the `Event` locally)

     But if it is handled by an `Interactor`, it means that this `Interactor` will need knowledge about `PFUser` (if I'm using Parse), and will have to change it's implementation if I stop using Parse (which I will).
- If it is handled by a `Gateway`, it means that the `Interactor` will just be forwarding the `join` call to the `Gateway`
  (`joinEventInteractor.join(eventId: String, callback: () -> ()) { eventGateway.join(eventId, callback: callback) }`).

Answer (score 1):

Your Gateway Should not have any business logic keep your logic inside inter-actors
and deal with gateway as boundaries only , from it name it's gateway it should point inward to your inter-actor only , in case you add any logic their then you violate Single Responsibility Principle